# Eclipse plugin installation/update issues

Tags: java, eclipse, configuration, eclipse-plugin

I've installed the following Team repository plugins (along with it's dependencies) for Eclipse Helios (using Eclipse updater).

- MercurialEclipse 1.7.1
- Subclipse 1.6.17
- Subversive SVN

All of these are the latest in Eclipse Marketplace. My problem is when I go to Eclipse "Preferences", under "Team" I only see CVS but under Eclipse Marketplace, I can see that these plugins are installed (it gives me an option to uninstall it).

- How do I configure my Team repositories to reflect under "Team" in Preferences?
- Also, there is an update for "Eclipse IDE for Java EE developers, but when I try to update it, the following error occurs:

  Cannot complete the install because of a conflicting dependency.
    Software being installed: Eclipse IDE for Java EE Developers 1.3.2.20110301-1807 (epp.package.jee 1.3.2.20110301-1807)
    Software currently installed: Shared profile 1.0.0.1276787175574 (SharedProfile_epp.package.jee 1.0.0.1276787175574)
    Only one of the following can be installed at once: 
      toolingepp.package.jee.configuration 1.3.2.20110301-1807
      toolingepp.package.jee.configuration 1.3.0.20100617-0521
    Cannot satisfy dependency:
      From: Shared profile 1.0.0.1276787175574 (SharedProfile_epp.package.jee 1.0.0.1276787175574)
      To: toolingepp.package.jee.configuration [1.3.0.20100617-0521]
    Cannot satisfy dependency:
      From: Eclipse IDE for Java EE Developers 1.3.2.20110301-1807 (epp.package.jee 1.3.2.20110301-1807)
      To: toolingepp.package.jee.configuration [1.3.2.20110301-1807]

How do I solve it? Yes, I've spent days Googling for this issue but none solved my problem.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I don't think it is a good idea to install both Subclipse and Subversive into one Eclipse installation. Both are dealing with Subversion resources which will lead to conflicts and situations in which Eclipse behaves strange.

Answer (score 1):

For the first question, if you go to Help -> About -> Installation Details -> plug-ins tab do you see, eg for Subversive:
[image: subversive plug-ins]

Comment: Sounds like they're not being loaded. Also in Help->About is an installed features section - what features are listed there for subversive?

Comment: it looks like it's not installed...is there anything for it in your plugins directory?

Comment: Only on `Installed Software` (found under Help -> About Eclipse -> Installation Details -> Installed Software).

Comment: Ok, try uninstalling svn and subversive, and re-sintalling ONE of them...I have a personal preference for subversive. Sounds like the install failed somehow. Also, in your workspace, look in .metadata at the log file, there may be some info there

Comment: That's not the point....MercurialEclipse is installed but I can't see it under "team"

Comment: and does it appear in the plugins section of help-about?

Comment: I redownloaded Eclipse & did a full update. I think because Eclipse couldn't update it's IDE, it caused lots of problem when installing plugins.

Answer (score 1):

Are you doing this on a Windows 7 machine?  Try running Eclipse as an administrator and then do the update.

Comment: It's not about running it as an administrator but it has to do with update depencency conflicts.

Answer (score 1):

Answering the second point of your question. Try executing eclipse as root/Administrator.

I had the same problem and I solved it.

Comment: That doesn't solve anything as I'm running Eclipse under administrator. It has to do with dependency issue.